# Using variables from one class in another class in Processing

Tags: class, variables, processing

I am new to programming and Processing. I am having a hard time accessing variables from one class in another class in Processing.

I have two classes a "ball" class and a class for collisions.

```java
class ball {


    float xBall; 
    float yBall; 
    int balldiameter = 20; 
    float oldxball, oldyball;
    boolean linehit; 
    color ballcolor = color(100, 200, 100); 
    float r; 
    float x;

    float speedx, speedy; 
    float speed = 6; 

    ball() {
        xBall = 200;
        yBall = 300;
        r = 2.8;
        boolean linehit;
    } // ball ()

    void ballUpdate() {

        float  px = xBall + cos(r)*(speed); 
        float  py = yBall + sin(r)*(speed);
        speedx = px - xBall; 
        speedy = py - yBall; 
        oldxball = xBall; 
        oldyball = yBall;
        xBall += speedx; 
        yBall += speedy;
        // display ball
        stroke(0); 
        fill(ballcolor); 
        ellipse (xBall, yBall, balldiameter, balldiameter);

    } //void ballUpdate()
} // class ball
```

collisions class:

```java
class collision {

    ball bl;

    collision() {
    } // collision ()

    void collisionUpdate() {

        bl = new ball();
        println(bl.r);
        println(bl.xBall);
        println(bl.yBall);
        println(bl.x);
```

Here I try accessing the xBall and other variables from the Ball Class inside the Collision Class, the code is running but the if-statements are never true. The variables stay never change.

```java
        if (bl.xBall < 0 || bl.xBall > width) { // side wall
            bl.x = PI - bl.r; 
            bl.r = bl.x;
            println("if 1");
        }

        if (bl.yBall < 0 || bl.yBall > height) { // top & bottom
            bl.x = TWO_PI - bl.r; 
            bl.r = bl.x;
            println("if 2");
        }
    } // void collisionUpdate()
} // class collision
```

I tried connecting the xBall,YBall, r and x variables from the ball class to the collision class         making the ball bounce on the walls.
the Main looks like this:

```java
ball bl;
collision cl;

void setup() {
    size(600, 600);

    bl = new ball();
    cl = new collision();
}


void draw() {
background(255);
bl.ballUpdate();
cl.collisionUpdate();
```

sorry for the noob question but im a beginner

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of these disconnected snippets?

Answer (score 0):

If you got two Balls instances witch one should be used by Collision class? I don't know the whole idea, so I can't really get where you are going...

Note that inside Collision you create a new Ball, and this is the ball that you try to check against the walls, but it is never updated. You would like to check the other ball, created in global scope.

Maybe the collission should be a method inside the ball class instead of a new class... As I said I don't know your goal but I see no reason for this design... Anyway... To make less changes to your code as possible, I think you got to pass a reference to the instance of ball to be checked, to the constructor of collision, like:

```java
Ball bl;
Collision cl;


void setup() {
  size(600, 600);

  bl = new Ball();
  cl = new Collision(bl);
}


void draw() {
  background(255);
  bl.ballUpdate();
  cl.collisionUpdate();
}


class Ball {

  float xBall; 
  float yBall; 
  int balldiameter = 20; 
  float oldxball, oldyball;
  boolean linehit; 
  color ballcolor = color(100, 200, 100); 
  float r; 
  float x;
  float speedx, speedy; 
  float speed = 6; 

  Ball() {
    xBall = 200;
    yBall = 300;
    r = 2.8;
    boolean linehit;
  } // ball ()


  void ballUpdate() {

    float  px = xBall + cos(r)*(speed); 
    float  py = yBall + sin(r)*(speed);
    speedx = px - xBall; 
    speedy = py - yBall; 
    oldxball = xBall; 
    oldyball = yBall;
    xBall += speedx; 
    yBall += speedy;
    // display ball
    stroke(0); 
    fill(ballcolor); 
    ellipse (xBall, yBall, balldiameter, balldiameter);
  } //void ballUpdate()
} // class ball




class Collision {

  Ball bl;

  Collision(Ball _bl) {
    bl = _bl;
  } // collision ()

  void collisionUpdate() {

    println(bl.r);
    println(bl.xBall);
    println(bl.yBall);
    println(bl.x);



    if (bl.xBall < 0 || bl.xBall > width) { // side wall
      bl.x = PI - bl.r; 
      bl.r = bl.x;
      println("if 1");
    }

    if (bl.yBall < 0 || bl.yBall > height) { // top & bottom
      bl.x = TWO_PI - bl.r; 
      bl.r = bl.x;
      println("if 2");
    }
  } // void collisionUpdate()
} // class collision
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need to check if the ball is colliding with any other ball ? or another object.? or both ?

if its just to see if they collide against each other i would suggest moving it as a function inside the ball class itself and then you have one method you can call in the draw every cycle which would check the entire array (i.e how ever many balls you have)

plus - you should really use PVector to store the lcoation of the object (ball) as it will help with future maths methods

Comment: completely off topic, just realized I've met you in Paris on the 22nd/23rd of April 2011

Comment: really ? @GeorgeProfenza were you in the masterclass with Harmut then ?

Comment: Yup, I remember you tested my audio reactive spider web with music from your phone :)